# Function app deployment slot swap doesn't swap

Tags: azure-functions, staging, azure-deployment-slots

I have a function app (durable function) and a staging slot:

staging slot contains these 2 functions:

[image]

production slot contains this one function:

[image]

After swapping, I see 2 functions in both staging slot and production slot:

[image]

My understabding is that after swapping, production slot will have the above 2 functions and staging slot will have what was in production slot earlier which is one function:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
// BICEP
var stagingSettings = [  
  {
    name: 'AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__durableTask__hubName'
    value: 'staging'
    slotSetting: true
  }
  {
    name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE'
    value: toLower('staging')
  }
]

resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots@2018-11-01' = {
  name: name
  kind: kind
  location: location
  properties: {
    clientAffinityEnabled: true
    enabled: true
    httpsOnly: true
    serverFarmId: resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', servicePlanName)
    siteConfig: {
      use32BitWorkerProcess : false
      appSettings: stagingSettings
    }
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}

// YML
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: 'deploy ${{ parameters.name }} function app (staging)'
  inputs:
    appType: 'functionapp'
    azureSubscription: ${{parameters.serviceConnection}}
    appName: '${{ parameters.name }}'
    Package: '${{ parameters.root }}/${{ parameters.name }}.zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'runFromPackage'
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    SlotName: "staging"
    resourceGroupName: 'rg'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

We tried to reproduce your issue from our end:

**Created 2 Functions (Orchestrator and Starter) of .NET 6 Stack in Production Slot:**

[image: prodslot2functions]

**Published 1 Function (Timer Trigger) to the Staging Slot of the same Azure Function App:**

[image: stagingslot1function]

**Operation 1: Doing the Swap from staging slot to production slot:**

[image: swapping]

[image: swapsuccess]

**Result: After Swapping from staging slot to production slot:**

[image: swapfirsttimersult]

**After 2nd Swap, the result will be like the Original:**

[image: swap2ndtimeresult]

**In your case**,

The **staging Slot** contains 2 functions:

- `OrchestratorFunction`
- `StarterFunction`

**Production Slot** contains 1 Function: Assume it as `TimerTrigger`.

**Your understanding is correct, After Swapping, 2 Functions will be in the Production Slot and 1 function will be in the Staging Slot.**

**AFAIK**,

Application in deployment slots has its own hostnames.

[image: HarisAzureNotes-DeploymentSlots]

**Deployment slots** are useful when you want to test the **different versions** of the applications.

Instead of creating one more web app/app service/function app and deploying it to the production slot for testing, with this deployment slots feature – each slot gets its own DNS Name.

After testing, you can perform a swap operation on the working version to the production slot from the testing slot and you can reverse swap if version 1 has to be deployed to the production slot.

**Note: To reflect the changes, it takes a minute or two sometimes due to latency of regions or some backend processing.**